# After I run my android app about 10 times from eclipse, get a INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error

Tags: android

My android project will not load the install the app file after I run the program about 10 times.

I get a

> [2012-05-29 17:03:33 - TellaFortune] Installation error:
>   INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error.

If I shut down the emulated and run the app again, it will run for about another 10 times.
The project does not do anything, just show a screen with a bunch of buttons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hi"
            android:textSize="74px" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/askaquastion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/askaquastion" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/askaquastion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/askaquastion" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/askaquastion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/askaquastion" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/askaquastion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/askaquastion" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/askaquastion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/askaquastion" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/askaquastion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/askaquastion" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Uninstall some app, your phone out of space and replug your USB cable

Answer (score 0):

U may need to increase the Android emulator's memory capacity.
Please try the following steps:

1. Right click the root of your Android Project, go to "**Run As**" then go to "**Run Configurations**"
2. Locate the "Android Application" node in the tree at the left, then select your project and go to the "**Target**" tab on the right side of the window look down for the "**Additional Emulator Command Line Options**" field (sometimes you'll need to make the window larger)
3. Finally paste "**-partition-size 1024**" there. Click Apply and then Run to use your emulator.

Comment: Hithank yoiu for the hint, but seemed like it made it worst.  One time a dialog popped up saying could not load app, then when i ran it i got the following from the console [2012-05-30 20:46:19 - TellaFortune] Installation failed due to invalid URI!
[2012-05-30 20:46:19 - TellaFortune] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-05-30 20:46:19 - TellaFortune] Launch canceled!

Comment: It don't seems to be an error related to memory space.  Try a project clean build and run. Uninstall the app before running it again.